# how do I set a hostname in yast?

Tags: networking, opensuse, hostname, hosts, yast

how do I set the hostname, FQDN, in yast?

I ran yast => network devices => network services => hostname/DNS:

```
 YaST2 - lan @ arrakis

  Network Settings                                                                               
  ┌Global Options──Overview──Hostname/DNS──Routing──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
  │┌Hostname and Domain Name───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│ 
  ││Hostname                                                                            Domain Name                                                                            ││ 
  ││arrakis▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ bounceme.net▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ││ 
  ││[ ] Change Hostname via DHCP                                                                                                                                               ││ 
  ││[x] Assign Hostname to Loopback IP                                                                                                                                         ││ 
  │└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│ 
  │Modify DNS configuration Custom Policy Rule                                                                                                                                  │ 
  │Use Default Policy▒▒▒▒▒↓ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒↓                                                                                                                                  │ 
  │┌Name Servers and Domain Search List────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│ 
  ││Name Server 1                                                                         ┌Domain Search──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐││ 
  ││▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ │bounceme.net                                                                       │││ 
  ││Name Server 2                                                                         │                                                                                   │││ 
  ││▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ │                                                                                   │││ 
  ││Name Server 3                                                                         │                                                                                   │││ 
  ││▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘││ 
  │└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│ 
  │                                                                                                                                                                             │ 
  │                                                                                                                                                                             │ 
  │
```

which made this alteration:

```
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # cat /etc/hosts
#
# hosts         This file describes a number of hostname-to-address
#               mappings for the TCP/IP subsystem.  It is mostly
#               used at boot time, when no name servers are running.
#               On small systems, this file can be used instead of a
#               "named" name server.
# Syntax:
#    
# IP-Address  Full-Qualified-Hostname  Short-Hostname
#

127.0.0.1       localhost 

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet 

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes 
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters 
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts 
127.0.0.2       arrakis.bounceme.net arrakis
linux-k7qk:~ #
```

and now I see that my hostname, apparently, is `arrakis` -- is that correct?

```
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # hostname
arrakis
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # ping arrakis
PING arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^C
--- arrakis.bounceme.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.039/0.047/0.053/0.005 ms
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # ping arrakis.bounceme.net
PING arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from arrakis.bounceme.net (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- arrakis.bounceme.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.037/0.040/0.002 ms
linux-k7qk:~ #
```

why does the prompt stay as `k7qk`?

Is the hostname actually the FQDN `arrakis.bounceme.net`?

(Please note that I'm not running a publicly available web server or anything like that, just on the LAN.  I only want to ensure that the hostname has been changed.)

uname shows:

```
linux-k7qk:~ # 
linux-k7qk:~ # uname -a
Linux arrakis 3.11.10-25-default #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 17:57:03 UTC 2014 (8210f77) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
linux-k7qk:~ #
```

While I'm **not** running arrakis as a publicly available web server, or anything like that, I want it set up for that eventuality.  Perhaps just on the LAN.

The FQDN `arrakis.bounceme.net` is registered on [noip.com](http://www.noip.com/) as a host name; part of their free services.  (No, that's not a plug for noip, well, it is in a round-a-bout way...)

Comment: Logout of your shell and then log back in.

Comment: I think that did it; although I might have had to hit "run" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your changes to be visible in your current shell you need to terminate the current session and log back in. Your hostname will have changed to `arakis`.

Explanation: a terminal session needs to be closed and re-opened for the profile to be re-read.